# Standalone Jersey Concurrent Invocations of ContainerRequestContext#abortWith(..) Hang Server

Tags: java, concurrency, jersey-2.0

I have a JAX-RS filter that uses `ContainerRequestContext#abortWith(..)` to signal authorization failure:

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class RequirePrincipalFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(RequirePrincipalFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
            throws IOException {
        if (requestContext.getSecurityContext() == null
                || requestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal() == null) {
            LOG.debug("No Principal");
            requestContext.abortWith(Response
                    .status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .entity(new ErrorRepresentation(Status.UNAUTHORIZED
                            .getStatusCode(), "Authorization required"))
                    .header("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer").build());
            LOG.debug("Request Aborted");
        }
    }
}
```

When successive requests are made such that `abortWith(..)` is invoked,
there is no problem. However, when two or more such requests are made
simultaneously, the service diverges such that no response is returned
and the
connection is hung. Any further requests to the server of any
kind--through the filter authorized, unauthorized, or even a request that
bypasses that filter altogether--also result in a hung connection with no response.

Both log statements are invoked for all applicable `abortWith(..)`
invocations. i.e. the code is not being hung on the method invocation
itself.

My question is: am I using the `abortWith(..)` facility correctly?
I suspect my own error here--otherwise I would expect to have
found someone else with this trouble.

I am running this with Jersey 2.17 from a Grizzly2 HTTP container, JVM is
Oracle JSE 1.8.0_45. I have also tried replacing the Grizzly container with the JDK container. The problem is the same.

As an experiment, I tried serializing the invocations to `abortWith(..)`
by calling it from within a synchronized block using the static LOG as monitor. The problem persists even if the invocations are serialized.